# InteropServices.COMException - Class not registered

Tags: vb.net, interop, com-interop, regsvr32

I'm having some problems in using a type that comes from an old unmanaged DLL.

```
gobjDPProject = New DP_Store_21.cProject
```

When I make this assignment an exception is threw

```
A first chance exception of type 
'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with 
CLSID {98214FEB-FE5C-495F-A926-F23DC62EEDD6} failed due to the following 
error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 
(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

To check the existence of this class I went to Regedit and found the component with the CLSID reported by the Exception, it exists and under the ProgID subFolder I can see the  `DP_Store_21.CProject` class.

Inside Visual Studio -> My Project -> References I can navigate inside the DP_Store_21 DLL (it's an Interop) and the CProject class is there.

Run `regsvr32 /pathTo DP_Store_21.dll` gives no problems and the other classes of the library are correctly instantiated, what I am missing ?

Comment: You are not using the ProgID so its presence doesn't tell you anything.  You'll have to navigate to HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Classes/CLSID.  With the typical problem that your program runs in 64-bit mode so can't use an old 32-bit component.  Or the component author modified his library so uses another CLSID.